# Is "tokenization/tokenize" written with a "z" or "s" in British English?

Tags: british-english

I can't find any examples of tokenization/tokenize written with an "s", and MS Word also corrects it to a "z" when set to UK English. Is there a reason this word does not follow the general rule of "sation"/"ise" or is it simply too uncommon to be found online or by auto-correct?

Comment: [***tokenise***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22tokenise%22) is effectively a brand new word (primarily created for / used in the cryptocurrency context; the full OED doesn't even list it yet). The general trend is for BrE spelling to fall into line with AmE, so you could reasonably go with ***tokenize*** even if your target readership is British. There's no "reason" beyond that (but note that my initial link into Google Books lists many instances of the "British" spelling).

Comment: Does that mean I can also reasonably use "tokenise"?

Comment: @FumbleFingers   'tokenise' isn't all that new; descriptions of the BBC BASIC programming language (developed in Britain for the BBC Micro and released in 1981) mentioned it as part of the process of running programs in the language, and [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/tokenize) says "tokenize (British tokenise)". The use is not unknown in the US, for example, a Stanford University article about the Fortran language has "It calls PARSE to tokenise individual records" Arguably the -ise spelling is more common in British English data processing circles. So a CV for lack of research.

Comment: It's common for (comparatively) new technical terminology to retain the original US spellings when used in the UK. So, for example, we use "tokenization" and "program" in those contexts rather than the British spellings, "tokenisation" and "programme".

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: Argue with the full Oxford English Dictionary, not me. I'm simply reporting the fact that they (still) don't list it. Obviously the word "token" has been around a long time, and it would always be trivial to "ad-hoc verbalise" it. [Here's](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22those+tokenised+if+we+may+use+such%22) a written instance (with "BrE spelling! :) from 1872 - but at least the writer recognises it mght be a stretch, since he says *...those tokenised **if we may use such a term***.

Comment: @KillingTime - In the UK, we've been using 'tokenise' (spelt thus) to mean 'replace elements of digital data with a code or more compact (or obfuscated) form' since the early 1980s, and probably a lot longer. I agree that mostly we do use 'program', but you do see 'programme' from time to time.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - if the context is data processing, I would prefer something more relevant thatn the OED.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: What do you need *any* such reference source for? The word is trivially created / regularly formed, and *in context* the meaning should always be clear. The OED is the nearest thing English (particularly, *British* English) has for an "authoritative last word" regarding "acceptable / correct" vocabulary and spelling. There ***is*** some point to asking about words like ***to prise** [open]*, but it really is a bit meaningless to ask about the "correct" spelling of a word like ***tokenize*** (using the OED or some other dictionary as a "reference").